# Is there any out of process, in-memory cache framework for .NET application

Tags: caching

Is there any in-memory caching framework that runs out of process and can be used by .NET desktop applications?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you perhaps taking of something like memcached? http://splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/

Comment: Yes, but the link you posted seems a little outdated? Current version is released in 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research.

Memcached is the one we choose. Follow this link to get things started.

http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62

Answer (score 1):

I use [AppFabric for Windows Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) successfully in production.

An nice performance feature the [Local Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334210.aspx), witch avoids (slow) deserializing of the cached object, with an additional local in-process cache:

> "The server stores objects in **serialized** form in the cache. When a cache client requests an object from the cache, the server sends it to the client over the network. The cache client then **deserializes** the object for use by the client application. To speed up the process of retrieving an object, **enable local cache**."

Bummer: Unfortunately AppFabric for Windows Server is **not supported on Windows Server Web Edition** (at least without some hacking - Reflector FTW):

> https://twitter.com/#!/ronljacobs/status/25903639754